# how to get value selected on other page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have dropdown to edit a form.
All ISBN records are listed in dropdown. The user will select the ISBN that he want to update. Now how to get which ISBN record was selected by that user?
My logic of dropdown is as follows:

```
function update()
{
$select_query="Select ISBN from book";
$select_query_run = mysql_query($select_query);
echo"<form method='post' action='update.php'><center>Select ISBN you want to  Update: ";
echo "<select name='isbn' id='isbn'>";
while ($select_query_array=mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
{
   echo "<option value='' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["ISBN"])." </option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo '<br><br><br><input type="submit" value="Update"></center></form>';
} After selecting ISBN the user will be navigated to update php page whoch is as follow:

<?php
$isbn=$_POST['isbn'];
echo "ISBN Selected: ".$isbn;
?>
```

Output of update page:
ISBN Selected:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you should try with this:

```
echo "<option value='' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["ISBN"])." </option>";
```

Instead of this:

```
echo "<option value='".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array['ISBN'])."' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["ISBN"])." </option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your value is empty in select box

```
 echo "<option value='' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["ISBN"])." </option>";
                     ^^
```

You need to add value in your select box

```
echo "<option value='".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array['ISBN'])."' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["ISBN"])." </option>";
```

Comment: and set attribute `selected` to the `<option>`

Comment: it will be selected by the user not him

Comment: Yes it will selected by user